# How to extract face details from a image

Tags: image-recognition, comparison, facial-recognition, image-segmentation

I am trying to make a face login application that authenticates the user when matching the registered face and the given face.
currently, the issue is I cant extract the face descriptions from the given face when the user is taking the photo in the night or the photo has a backlight.

currently, I am using [JavaScript API for face detection and face recognition in the browser and nodejs with tensorflow.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/)

can anyone suggest any good face detection and comparison algorithm that resolve my current issues, that will be very helpful for me

Now I am extracting face descriptions from the face and using the Euclidean distance equation is used for comparing the similarity of the images. if any good methods for comparison, please suggest

Comment: AI.SE doesn't deal with implementation details. I would suggest you head over to DataScience.SE for a better answer.

Comment: @DuttaA *I cant extract the face descriptions from the given face when the user is taking the photo in the night or the photo has a backlight.* ... and *can anyone suggest any good face detection and comparison algorithm that resolve my current issues, that will be very helpful for me*. On these lines the question seems on topic.

Comment: @naive head over to the chat group 'The Singularity', you may understand what I'm talking about.